# Teclado subindo antes da view subir

Tags: ios, teclado, view

Como diz o enunciado: Assim que eu toco num `input` o teclado sobe e depois a `view` sobe. Eu gostaria de saber o que eu estou fazendo de errado.

**PS**: Além disso, entre o teclado e a view, existe um espaço preto e o `scroll` da view ainda funciona, assim deixando-o ainda mais feio com o efeito.

```
#pragma mark - UITextField Delegate

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *guestlistName = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;

    if (buttonIndex == 1) // Cancel
        return;

    if (guestlistName == nil || [guestlistName length] == 0)
        return;
}

// Keyboard handling junk below
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

 - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
 UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = nil;
}

- (void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
activeField = textView;
}

- (void) textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    activeField = textView;
}

- (void) dismissKeyboard {
    [activeField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um exemplo utilizando Swift, mas a pegada é mais ou menos a mesma.

Você também pode optar por animar a view do UIViewController como um todo da seguinte forma:

**Atributos:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var search: UITextField!
var isKeyboardLifted: Bool = false
```

**ViewWillAppear**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    var center: NSNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    center.addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    center.addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

**Métodos dos selectors**

```
// MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
// Selector do keyboardWillShow
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    var info: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = keyboardSize.height

    if (!isKeyboardLifted) {
        self.isKeyboardLifted = true
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.view.frame.origin.y - keyboardHeight), self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

// Selector do keyboardWillHide
func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    var info: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = keyboardSize.height

    if (isKeyboardLifted) {
        self.isKeyboardLifted = false
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.view.frame.origin.y + keyboardHeight), self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

// Selector do UIGesture
func dismissKeyboard() {
    self.search.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer este deslocamento com ou sem notificações de sistema. Já ocorreu comigo de `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` e `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` gerarem um delay que impedia a animação do deslocamento ser compatível com a animação da entrada do teclado. Caso isto esteja ocorrendo com você faça desta forma:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    //Deixar o scrollView maior permite que o usuário role a página até o fim sem precisar esconder o teclado.
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height + kbSize.height);

    //No método "viewDidLoad" da respectiva classe, valorize uma variável global 'tamanhoDeslocamentoTeclado' com o valor 0.
    tamanhoDeslocamentoTeclado = 0;

    CGRect frameRelativo = [textField convertRect:textField.bounds toView:self.scrollView];

    //DISTANCIA_TECLADO_PROXIMA é um define onde você escolhe a qual distância do textField/textView o teclado deve ficar. Entre 8.0 e 15.0, por exemplo. 
    int alturaIdeal = self.view.frame.size.height - (kbSize.height) - textField.frame.size.height - DISTANCIA_TECLADO_PROXIMA;

    if(frameRelativo.origin.y > alturaIdeal)
    {
        tamanhoDeslocamentoTeclado = frameRelativo.origin.y - alturaIdeal;
    }

    if(tamanhoDeslocamentoTeclado!=0)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, tamanhoDeslocamentoTeclado);}
                     completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //No método "viewDidLoad" da respectiva classe, valorize uma variável global 'tamanhoOriginalScroll' com o tamanho original do scrollView. Este tamanho é o que o componente ocupa quando não há teclado nenhum na tela.

    if(tamanhoDeslocamentoTeclado!=0)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);self.scrollView.contentSize = tamanhoOriginalScroll;}
                     completion:nil];
   }
}
```

É possível ainda que seu scrollView esteja dentro de uma outra view container (ou de várias outras), sendo necessário neste caso saber a posição do scrollView em relação a view base do viewController pai. Este deslocamento é mais avançado pois exige um variável extra de controle, mas acredito não ser o seu caso.